# Creating function & then calling it when needed

Tags: php, function

I dont know much about PHP functions.I want to print the name inside the function when it is called on clicking the button.I have tried different ways and even searched for it in google.Need help...

```
<?PHP
function writeName()
{
echo "Kai Jim Refsnes";
}

Echo "<form>
<input type='button' onClick='writeName();' style='position:fixed;bottom:0px;left:0px;width:100%;'>
</form>";
?>
```

Comment: You can not call php functions from html page. `onClick='writeName();'` will try to call a javascript function `writeName()`, which is not defined here. So, to call php function you should use ajax call to it.

Comment: Please get yourself acquainted with the these terms first : `client side` & `server side`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide you with three alternatives:

**1.** Using ***pure PHP***.PHP is `server-side` Changes in pure PHP takes place in the following way

- Data is sent to the server
- Data is processed at the server
- After processing data is responded from the server to the user
- During the above processes page reloads and when complete data is received at the client reload stops.

So using pure PHP i can figure out only one way to call function on button click.I can be done as follows:

```
<?PHP
function writeName()
{
echo "Kai Jim Refsnes";
}

if(isset($_GET['submit']))
{
writeName();
}
?>

<form action="#">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" style="position:fixed;bottom:0px;left:0px;width:100%;" />
</form>
```

**2.** Using ***Javascript***.Javascript is `client-side`.It doesnt reload the page.

```
<script>
function writeName()
{
document.write="Kai Jim Refsnes";
}
</script>
<button onclick="writeName();">submit</button>
```

**3.** Using ***AJAX***.With AJAX you can combine both PHP and Javascript.For this *simply print a message* AJAX will be too much but for larger/complex data transfers between server and client without reloading AJAX is much helpful.

AJAX refrences: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ; http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a PHP function from JavaScript.

PHP is interpreted on the server side and JavaScript on the client side.

You could use an [AJAX request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or you could write a JavaScript function at runtime with the PHP

Something like:

```
echo <<<END
<form>
    <input type='button' onClick='function writeName() { document.write("{$php_var_name}") }' style='position:fixed;bottom:0px;left:0px;width:100%;'>
</form>
END
```

Comment: I was thinking about that.  Obviously, he isn't understanding the difference between the server code and client code, but in ASP.NET, you have script methods which allow you to call code behind methods from Javascript, I was thinking there had to be something similar in PHP.

Comment: @jessel no, it's not possible.

Comment: i do know the difference between server code and client code.

Comment: i actually want to create a "Tap to load" button. I thought it will be possible with the use of function.so what should i do for such script.

Comment: I've updated my answer with some more information. If you want to go back and update your question with more details regarding the "tap to load" functionality, I'll expand my answer.

Comment: I am using mysql to get results and then show it with php.I want to show only limited no of records.If user wants to see more records he can click on tap to load.Please help.If you still need script which i have written till now i can do so.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run on the server side, so you should use AJAX, which allows you to run PHP after a page has already loaded.

AJAX is asynchronous javascript - you basically use Javascript to query a PHP page on your server, and you receive a response that you then can print to your page.